# Using StructureMap with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, structuremap

I am developping a cross-platform application based on Xamarin Forms.
In my application, I want to use StructureMap for IoC.

I made a sample application. As soon as I add StructureMap package (4.6.1), I get an error on deploy :

> Synchronizing files... Building and running... Built with 1 messages.
>   (1,1): error: Failed to load assembly from stream:
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the
>   path
>   "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/External/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.loader/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.5/System.Runtime.Loader.dll".
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode
>   mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share,
>   System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous,
>   System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0017d] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor
>   (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess
>   access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor
>   (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
>   at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    at
>   .$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00012] in <5a7d391011b47c3aa745038310397d5a>:0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0     --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not
>   find a part of the path
>   "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/External/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.loader/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.5/System.Runtime.Loader.dll".
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode
>   mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share,
>   System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous,
>   System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0017d] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor
>   (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess
>   access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor
>   (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
>
>   at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    at
>   <StartupCode$Continuous-Core-Droid>.$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00012] in <5a7d391011b47c3aa745038310397d5a>:0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0     --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path
>   "/data/user/0/com.xamarin.live/files/External/.nuget/packages/system.runtime.loader/4.3.0/ref/netstandard1.5/System.Runtime.Loader.dll".
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode
>   mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share,
>   System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous,
>   System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0017d] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor
>   (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess
>   access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor
>   (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
>   at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    at
>   .$LocalFileSystem+Upsight-IFileSystem-OpenReadAsync@49-1.Invoke () [0x00012] in <5a7d391011b47c3aa745038310397d5a>:0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in
>   <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0 <--- <---
>
> Failed to debug your app.

I use Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.1) and Xamarin Forms 3.0.0.482510.

I also have the same type of issue with Entity Framerwork Core SQLite

Have you ever encountered this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you don't use StructureMap on Xamarin.Forms as it is unsupported:

> StructureMap 4.5+ will not work on Xamarin iOS because it depends on
>   System.Reflection.Emit, which is not available in MonoTouch.
>   StructureMap 4.4 works for at least basic scenarios on that platform.
>   Nobody in the core StructureMap team is currently working with Xamarin
>   mobile runtimes, but we are interested in verifying StructureMap on
>   new platforms if any volunteers are interested in helping us out.

http://structuremap.github.io/get-structuremap/

Comment: OK. And what about EntityFrameworkCore SQLite ? The same ?

Comment: Sqlite is supported but I'm not sure about ef core.